# Converting variable to type 'string' in CMake

Tags: makefile, scripting, cmake

Please tell me how does one convert a variable to a variable of type string in CMake.

I have a variable that contains both digits and letters. Say of the form: "Ax3.0.1". I don't know exactly what type of variable CMake sees this at but I want to convert it to a string so I can itterate through it. Please tell me how can I do that. Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried to access the variable in this form already `"${variable}"`? You need the enclosing quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, every variable in CMake is a *string*. However, unlike to many other programming languages, in CMake *string* is **not an array of characters**. So one cannot *directly* iterate over characters in the string with `foreach`.

The closest thing is iteration over character indicies with extracting character by index:

```
set(var "Ax3.0.1")

# Compute length of the string
string(LENGTH ${var} var_length)
# But foreach needs the last index, not a range.
math(EXPR last_char_index "${var_length} - 1")

message("Characters in string '${var}':")
foreach(char_index RANGE ${last_char_index}) # Iterate over indicies
    # Create variable 'char' which contains specific character of the string.
    string(SUBSTRING "${var}" "${char_index}" "1" char)
    message("${char}")
endforeach()
```

As you can see, this looks quite ugly. Actually, for extract specific character(s) from the string *regular expressions* are usually used.

Comment: Can you please tell me how could I extract from a variable with that value(Ax3.0.1...) extract the first three digits with a regex? I can't get my head around that :(

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571176/3440745) to your previous question given you a regular expression. What is wrong with it?